# Can I leave the UK on a Colombian passport?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, colombian-citizens

I have lost my British passport and have a flight booked for Saturday. I have applied for a new one but it could take up to 7 working days which is too long for me to wait. I am travelling to Colombia and my question is, am i able to fly out of the UK with my Colombian passport? Or will border control not allow me to leave without a British passport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The UK does not have border control checkpoints for departing air passengers.  You will be able to leave.

Comment: Thank you for replyingso promptly, do you know if at check in, they will allow me to travel on the Colombian Passport? (The colombian Passport doesn’t have any Visa on it)

Comment: If you have a direct flight from the UK to Colombia it should be no problem. The airline will only care about your right to enter Colombia which as Colombian passport satisfies. OTOH if your flight involves transit in other countries then that may well be a problem.

Comment: @Straveler The airline won't prevent you from leaving because of a lack of a UK visa on your Colombian passport, but Peter Green makes an excellent point.  You may have problems if you have to transit through any country that requires a visa of Colombian passport holders.  In such a case, the airline will not let you board.  The only likely such countries for this itinerary are the US or Canada (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Colombian_citizens).  You will also need your UK passport to return to the UK, so you should figure out how to arrange that.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica fair enough, but that is not a UK border control checkpoint for passengers leaving the UK; it is a French border control checkpoint for passengers entering the Schengen area.  There are no such "juxtaposed controls" (as they are known) in UK airports.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica ah, I skimmed over your mention of a UK departure check without it registering.  I wasn't aware of that.  I'll edit the answer.